# UPDATE using different conditions

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT gg.itemid,gi.id,gi.courseid, gg.userid, gg.finalgrade 
FROM pauls_grade_grades gg, pauls_grade_items gi 
WHERE gg.itemid = gi.id AND gg.userid =36 AND gi.courseid = 13
```

I want the update query for the same select query above.

```
UPDATE pauls_grade_grades 
SET pauls_grade_grades.finalgrade = 28 
WHERE usermodified IS NULL AND userid = 36 AND 
       itemid IN (SELECT gi.id 
                  FROM pauls_grade_items gi 
                  WHERE gi.courseid=13)
```

Is this the right way to write a UPDATE query

Comment: Does your update query work? then its right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is correct

if you can't update the data then that means there row doesn't exist. 
Try taking the where clause and add it to a SELECT statement and make sure you can select something first ..for example

```
select * from pauls_grade_grades 
WHERE usermodified IS NULL AND userid = 36 AND itemid IN 
(SELECT gi.id 
FROM pauls_grade_items gi 
WHERE gi.courseid=13)
```

Then add the where back to your update statement

```
UPDATE pauls_grade_grades SET finalgrade = 29 WHERE usermodified IS NULL AND userid = 36 AND itemid IN  (SELECT gi.id 
FROM pauls_grade_items gi 
WHERE gi.courseid=13)
```

Comment: the select query was giving the correct output and how could we update  in the same way

Comment: could it be possible pauls_grade_grades.finalgrade is a varchar column ?

Comment: but I have finalgrade type as decimal(10,5)

Answer (score 0):

The query that you have written for update will work without failure.
Let me explain what your query does.
You are using subquery for update. First the subquery

```
SELECT gi.id 
FROM pauls_grade_items gi 
WHERE gi.courseid=13
```

will get executed. The values that it return will be replaced by this subquery in the main query.

Comment: @user1586609 may be it is not satisfying the conditions after the `where` clause.

Comment: Are you sure the the statement under the WHERE clause is met?

Comment: I am getting the correct row by executing the query select * from pauls_grade_grades WHERE usermodified IS NULL AND userid = 36 AND itemid IN (SELECT gi.id FROM pauls_grade_items gi WHERE gi.courseid=13)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use your `SELECT` query to write an `UPDATE` query.
Try this:

```
UPDATE pauls_grade_grades gg, pauls_grade_items gi 
SET gg.finalgrade = 28
WHERE gg.itemid = gi.id AND gg.userid =36 AND gi.courseid = 13
    AND usermodified IS NULL
```

Comment: it was showing an error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM pauls_grade_grades gg, pauls_grade_items gi WHERE gg.itemid = gi.id AND g' at line 3"

Comment: ok, it was for SQL Server. Try again, i had fix it for MySQL version.